# Case statement not working as expected in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field in the database that contains a lot of empty/null rows.  I am trying to create a case statement that changes this to "Empty Field" or something similar so that when it is displayed to the user, they will have an indication that the row has no data for that column but for some reason it is not working.  When I select the data without the case statement, I get either a string or an empty field as should be.  When I add the case statement, every row comes back as `{null}` regardless to what is in that column.  I have used similar case statements many times but this has me baffled.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN col_name = TRIM('') THEN 'Empty Field'
         END col_name
FROM table_name
```

I also tried `LIKE` in place of the equals sign as well as `NULL` instead of `TRIM('')`

working solution:

```
SELECT NVL(TRIM(col_name), 'Empty Field') AS col_name
FROM table_name
```

Comment: There is no `CAST` statement in your code. Did you mean to write `CASE` in the title of your question? (And `TRIM('')` doesn't really make sense)

Comment: Ops. Yes, I meant to say `CASE`, not `CAST` and corrected it.  Why does `TRIM('')` not make.  The column I am trying to change is empty or null.

Comment: `trim()` removes leading and trailing spaces from a string. The string `''` does not have any spaces, so there is no need to call `trim()` on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `nvl()` as codenheim suggested, but further to the answers about your original solution, you have no `else` clause - so nothing is matching against `= null` and you never get `Empty field`, but everything that *doesn't* match is then defaulted to null anyway. You'd need to do:

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN col_name IS NULL THEN 'Empty Field'
     ELSE col_name
     END AS col_name
FROM table_name
```

But that would be the same as

```
SELECT NVL(col_name, 'Empty Field') AS col_name
FROM table_name
```

You suggested that still isn't working but weren't very specific; but your original use of `trim` makes me wonder if you have some values that are not null but only consist of spaces - so they would still just be spaces afterwards. If that is the case and you want to treat all-spaces as null then you could do:

```
SELECT NVL(TRIM(col_name), 'Empty Field') AS col_name
FROM table_name
```

If you have other whitespace - just a `tab` perhaps - then you could use a regular expression to strip that out instead, e.g.:

```
SELECT NVL(REGEXP_REPLACE(col_name, '^[[:space:]]+$', NULL),
    'Empty Field') AS col_name
FROM table_name;
```

[SQl Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2347b/1).

Comment: It makes me think he has a CHAR() field with spaces instead.

Comment: To clarify "still isn't working" when using `NVL()` it was returning the same results as if I was not using it at all.  Your suspicion if spaces looks to be correct.  I used `VL(TRIM(col_name), 'Empty Field')` and it works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In Oracle, `''` in VARCHAR context is treated as NULL

You can just use NVL(col_name,'Default Value')

```
select NVL(col_name, 'Empty Field') from table_name
```

TRIM('') is NULL in Oracle SQL, so has no effect.

```
SQL> set null NULL
SQL> select trim('') from dual;

T
-
N
U
L
L
```

As far as your CASE statement, the problem lies in your use of equalty with NULL. You cant say where NULL = anything, it is false. NULL is not equal to anything, not even itself. You need to use:

```
WHERE col_name IS NULL
```

IS NULL and = NULL are not the same.

```
SQL> select case when id = trim('') then 'Empty' end from nulls;

CASEW
-----
NULL

SQL> select case when id = null then 'Empty' end from nulls;

CASEW
-----
NULL

SQL> select case when id is null then 'Empty Field' end from nulls;

CASEW
-----
Empty Field      <--- DATA!
```

If this does not work, perhaps you have spaces in your data. Test that by using SQLPLUS - SET NULL NULL command I showed to verify it is truly NULL.

Comment: No, in your SQL you've said "WHERE col_name = TRIM('')" which is like saying "WHERE col_name = NULL", which returns no results. You cannot compare to NULL with = . You must use IS NULL instead. See my answer for samples.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is return a default value in a query when values are null, then you don't need the CASE statement at all. Oracle provides a simple function, NVL(). I added the additional explanation for completeness.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me. For some reason, `NVL()` is still not working.  I looked at the Oracle docs and that is most certainly the best solution but maybe something odd seems to be going on.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do is to use codenheim example.But for the sake of clarity when you check a NULL column in oracle you have to use IS NULL

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN col_name IS NULL THEN 'Empty Field'
     ELSE col_name
     END AS col_name
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: This returns every row as `{null}`. I know this should work but for some reason, it is not.